# How do I make an element display for some time then fade away and when i refresh my page it doesn't show?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a log in in page where by when I i log in it takes me to my homepage which has a `<div class="alert alert-success`> message.
I want this message to show for like 5 seconds then it fades out.
How do I do that??
Also when i refresh my page I don't want the message to show again unless i log out then log in again.

this is some of the code:
    
        
            ×
            **success!** Login successfull!
        
This is supposed to show when i have successfully logged in.

Comment: Do you have a database ?

Comment: You should really add some code. In the meantime, I should point you to [cookies!](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) Create a cookie when a user logs in and use [Javascript in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596218/how-to-write-javascript-code-inside-php)  to keep the alert-success message hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use php to create set a session variable and then clear it after it's been displayed.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['new_message'] = true;

if(isset($_SESSION['new_message']){
//your code to display the message
session_destroy;
}
```

To fade after 5 seconds use jquery

```
$('#div').delay(5000).fadeOut(400)
```