# how to write javascript inside php tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to write a javascript inside php tags my javascpript is here

```
<script>  
    $('#img').attr("src","getImage.php?id="+);
    $('#img').show();
</script>
```

and what I am doing is here

```
   <?php
    echo "<script>";  
    echo " $('#img').attr(\"src\",\"getImage.php?id=\"+1); ";
    echo " $('#img').show(); ";
    echo "</script>";
    ?>
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write javascript code inside php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596218/how-to-write-javascript-code-inside-php)

Comment: You need to `echo` the whole JS inside the `php` tag because PHP doesn't know anything of what you're doing with it. Like, `<?php
   echo "<script> your code here  </script>";
?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I was doing wrong is , I was echoing the js in parts. What I needed to was something like this

```
    <?php
    echo " <script>  
    $('#img').attr(\"src\",\"getImage.php?id=\"+2);
    $('#img').show();
    </script> ";
    ?>
```

whole js in just 1 peice is the key here.

Comment: closing the PHP tag and reopen it will be easy for long codes

Answer (score 1):

Your script tag is just like any other HTML tag, just close your PHP tag before opening it:

```
?>

<script>  
    $('#img').attr("src", "getImage.php?id=" + 1);
    $('#img').show();
</script>

<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the reason you are echoing javascript via php is that u want to be able to generate dynamically the number you add to the end of the image source/src tag. you can do it as follows...

As far as your php file is saved with extension of '.php' you can do this without errors:

```
<?php $n = 2; //Declaration of n ?>
<script>
$("#img").attr("src", <?php echo "\"getImage.php?id=$n\"" ?>);
$("#img").show();
</script>
```

And that is it, just use the php open and closing tag where u need to output something dynamic... other than that, leave pure javascript out side to avoid confusion. 
Make sure u provided a link to jquery library as well as i can see that from your syntax u intend to use jquery.
hope this helps. :-)