# jquery doesnt work when using this approach

Tags: javascript, jquery

my html form to generate the info before submiting it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/submit.js"></script>

    <form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
     <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"required>
     <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"required>
     <input type="text" id="mname" name="mname"required>

    <input type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="GENERATE" />
</form>
  <div id="results1">
    <hr>
  </div>
```

//submit.js

```
function SubmitFormData() {
    var lname = $("#lname").val();
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var mname = $("#mname").val();
    $.post("generate.php", { lname: lname, fname: fname, mname: mname},
    function(data) {
     $('#results1').html(data);
     $('#myForm')[0].reset();
    });
}
```

Get it using //generate.php

```
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    echo display_records($fname,$mname,$lname);
        //add javascript here ex (disabled submit button if its empty OR add prevent double submit//
    <form>
   //form goes here 
    </form>
```

disabled form if its empty http://jsfiddle.net/He4Kv/7/

flow:

```
generate fullname(submit.js) > display result with form(generate.php) > then submit
```

The problem is when adding javascript inside generate.php it doesnt work.(adding disabled script doesnt work inside generate.php)

Comment: can you add information on what is `it doesnt work`?

Comment: @guradio if you add disabled script or any javascript inside generate.php it doesnt work (not functioning).

Comment: Are you asking how to write js in php? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596218/how-to-write-javascript-code-inside-php