# How do I run JS inside PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im trying to create a website and write now I'm creating my login Page. I have been successful in checking whether the user exists. But I want to return an error if it is wrong and that is possible only using JavaScript. My PHP file is run using AJAX. I have tried many solutions but none have worked. I tried putting the script tags in echo but that didn't work. So basically I want to run my JavaScript code inside PHP.

My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NHG</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/resposive.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jQuery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="abhimanyu">
      <p>"Life will test you but remember this, when you walk up a mountain your legs get stronger"</p>
    </div>
    <div id="arjun">
      <p>"There is no such thing as a failed experiment, only experiments with unexpected outcomes"</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="bheem">
      <p>"Do not look where you fell, but where you slipped."</p>
    </div>
    <div id="eklavya">
      <p>"Sometimes life touches one person with a bouquet and another with a thorn bush, but the first may find a wasp in the flowers, and the second may discover roses among the thorns."</p>
    </div>
    <header>
            <div id="main-head">
              <!--      REMEMBER TO CHANGE THE COLOR OF HEADING        -->
              <a href="#" id="main-heading"><h2><span>sKool</span><span>Talk</span></h2></a>
            </div>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a40bbe047e.png" alt="avatar" id="schoolAvatar" align="middle">
          <div id="admissionNumberDiv">
            <form method="get" id="admissionNumber">
              <input type="text" name="admissionNumber" id="admissionNumberBox" placeholder="Enter your asmission number..."/>
              <br>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your Password...">
              <br>
              <button type="submit" id="admissionSubmitButton">
                <p>Next</p>
              </button> 
              <br>
              <p id="loginErrorMessage"></p>
            </form>
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <br>
    <footer>
      <div class="footerHR">
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#schoolSubmitButton').click(function(){
    var schoolName = $('#schoolNameBox').val().toLowerCase();
    switch (schoolName) {
      case 'new horizon gurukul':
        $('#container').remove();
        $.get("NHGLogin.php", function(data){
          var NGHLogin = $(data).find('div#container');
          $('body').append(NGHLogin);
        });
        break;
      default:
        $('#schoolErrorMessage').text('Please Enter a valid school name, still if invalid schoold does not exist!').css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
  var name = $('#admissionNumberBox').val();
  var pwd = $('#password').val();
  var dataString = "admissionNumber: " + name;
  $('#admissionSubmitButton').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'php/login.php',
      method: 'get',
      cache: 'true',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {'admissionNumber': name, 'password': pwd},
      success: function(response){
        $('#container').append(response);
        $('body').append(response);
        $('#loginErrorMessage').text(response);
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and my PHP:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $dbserver = "localhost:3306";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpass = "";
  $dbname = "NewHorizonGurukul";
  $username = $_GET['admissionNumber'];
  $password = $_GET['password'];
   
  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
                     
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE AdmissionNumber='$username' AND Password='$password';";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $numRows = $result->num_rows;
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    
  if ($numRows > 0) {
    header('location: ../random.php');
    echo "<script>window.location('../random.php')<script/>";
  } else {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
            'document.getElementById("loginErrorMessage").innerHTML = "Pleas enter a valid username or password";',
            '</script>';
  } 
 ?>
```

Here's what it returns:

[image]

Comment: try to console your Ajax response , if its properly print or not..!!

Comment: what is the issue here? Any syntax error?

Comment: Check this answer from another post. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10596296/3973543](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10596296/3973543)

Comment: Thats what i did in the above code but it didn't work. It just returns that as a string.

Comment: It's not a syntax error it just echos a string instead of running whats inside the script tags

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of error? mean returned string

Comment: is it an ajax request?

Comment: you can't do this in php in this situation you have to do this in javascript after ajax  response

Comment: @shreyas , please try with my answer , it is very easy to use , ever successful ,i am using this in all my websites.

Comment: It wasnt working for me. But if it was for you i'l just go through the whole code again.

Comment: `I want to run my JavaScript code inside PHP` - PHP runs on server, javascript runs in browser - you can't run javascript "inside" PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Your code with below code. and try

```
//JS Part: 
$("#admissionNumber").on('submit',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
        $data = $(this).serialize();
        $URL = 'php/'+$(this).attr('data-param-uri')+'.php';
        _Form.__Link($URL, $data,function (return_data){
            if(typeof (return_data.url) !== 'undefined' && return_data.success === true ){
                $(document).find("#loginErrorMessage").html("");
                window.location.href = return_data.url;
            }else{
                $(document).find("#loginErrorMessage").html(return_data.msg);
            }
        });
  });  
   _Form = {
       __Link: function ($url, $data, callback){
            $.ajax({
                url: $url,
                data: $data,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                cache:false,
                success: function (data) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
   });
  $("#admissionNumberBox").on('blur',function(e){
      $(document).find("#loginErrorMessage").html("");
  });
  $("#password").on('blur',function(e){
      $(document).find("#loginErrorMessage").html("");
  });

// PHP Part: 
function loginUser($FORMDATA){
    global $conn;

    if(empty($FORMDATA)){ $RESP['success'] = false;$RESP['msg'] = "NullData";return json_encode($RESP);}

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE AdmissionNumber='".$FORMDATA['admissionNumber']."' AND Password='".$FORMDATA['password']."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    //if only one user is there than is valid
    if(($result->num_rows) == 1){
        $RESP['success'] = true;
        $RESP['msg'] = "Logged in successfully..!!";
        $RESP['url'] = 'random.php';
    }else{
        $RESP['success'] = false;
        $RESP['msg'] = "Please check credentials and try again..!!";
    }
    return json_encode($RESP);// Js Accept Json Responses
}
```

Comment: what is the error occur in that ? if your ajax request reached successfully than ,it revert you the response. in two ways either ECHO or return array.

Comment: The following error is given: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/School/php/login.php on line 31

Comment: sorry , please use " print_r($RESP) " instead of echo :-)

Comment: now it works :) but then it doesnt change the value of `#loginErrorMessage`

Comment: you can update the value of #loginErrorMessage when the login credentials are proper...

Comment: Ok i entered the chat room

Answer (score 0):

You could send an error is your script like:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));
```

instead of your

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'document.getElementById("loginErrorMessage").innerHTML = "Pleas enter a valid username or password";',
        '</script>';
```

and then catch the error using the error attribute in ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'php/login.php',
  method: 'get',
  cache: 'true',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {'admissionNumber': name, 'password': pwd},
  success: function(response){
    $('#container').append(response);
    $('body').append(response);
    alert(response);
  }
  error   : function(){alert('An Error Has Occurred')} 
});
```

Comment: The thing is I want the error message to be displayed in `p#loginErrorMessage`

Comment: hrm ok I did not get that was what you wanted at first. I would remove the "" and just echo your message

Comment: oops, hit return too soon. I would use error : function(data){$('#loginErrorMessage').html(data)} and then just echo your error message as echo "please enter valid.."

Comment: hrm actually, I think you would want to `error : function(){$('#loginErrorMessage').html("Please enter a valid user name')}` but still send the `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));`